# Invoke function like Foo(int num = 2048)

Tags: c#, function

How do I call to function with signeture like:

`public void Foo(int num = 2048)`

I tried `Foo(null);` but it thorws null exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is an optional parameter, you can just call

```
Foo();
```

or

```
Foo(someNumber);
```

---

If the signature was a nullable type

```
Foo(int? num);
```

You could use call

```
Foo(null);
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)

[Nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)